# pg_cron failing when using transaction block

Tags: postgresql, pg-cron

I have a query as a transaction, using `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`. When I run this as a query it succeeds, however when I run it through `pg_cron` I receive the following error:

`FATAL: EndTransactionBlock: unexpected state BEGIN`

`BEGIN;TRUNCATE app_top50;INSERT INTO xxx...;COMMIT;`

Googling the error returns very few results.

Comment: Is this wrapped in a function or a procedure or just passed to pg_cron as a naked string?  Please show us.

Answer (score 3):

[`pg_cron` source code](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron/blob/main/src/pg_cron.c#L2157) has a comment about it:

```
/*
 * We don't allow transaction-control commands like COMMIT and ABORT
 * here.  The entire SQL statement is executed as a single transaction
 * which commits if no errors are encountered.
*/
```

So you don't need to add `BEGIN; ... COMMIT;` block. Just add queries and they will be executed as single transaction.